# How should the contour lines of a convex function look?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, graphing-functions

My book asks me to sketch the contour lines of a convex function and discuss why it looks like this.

I've been thinking about this for a while. My guess is that each contour would have to be convex too, since if it's not, then I found a place of intersection with the shape where a line between two points of itself don't lie in the shape.

Is there anything more to consider?

Comment: The level sets $\{ x | f(x) \le \alpha \}$ are convex so the contours will bound convex sets. However, the level sets may be convex but $f$ is not necessarily so.

Comment: what do you mean by bould convex sets? A level set shouldn't be $f(x) = \alpha$?